# What does flex project Eclipse Clean actually does?

Tags: eclipse, apache-flex, adobe, flash, swc

I have a flex application associated with java project. Flex project is linked to one more swc project. I build both of them together using maven.
After build, the size of generated swc is 2.5mb.But when I deploy the application and manually clean the projects using **project->clean->clean all projects**. I have observed that size of swc has got reduced to 1.7mb.

Can anyone tell me what magic is the eclipse doing while cleaning the projects?

After digging further, I observed that there are some unused nonrefernced images in my project directory structure. Do they got excluded while cleaning?

Need immediate help.

Here is compiler settings..

```
    <compilerSourcePath>
      <compilerSourcePathEntry kind="1" linkType="1" path="colt-lib-flex/src/main/resources"/>
    </compilerSourcePath>
    <libraryPath defaultLinkType="0">
      <libraryPathEntry kind="4" path="">
        <excludedEntries>
          <libraryPathEntry kind="3" linkType="1" path="${PROJECT_FRAMEWORKS}/libs/flex.swc" useDefaultLinkType="false"/>
        </excludedEntries>
      </libraryPathEntry>
      <libraryPathEntry kind="3" linkType="1" path="D:/eclipse/m2repo/com/jpmc/bdias/matrix/WKSTFxFrameWork/1.0/WKSTFxFrameWork-1.0.swc" useDefaultLinkType="false"/>
      <libraryPathEntry kind="3" linkType="1" path="D:/eclipse/m2repo/com/adobe/as3corelib/1.0/as3corelib-1.0.swc" useDefaultLinkType="false"/>
      <libraryPathEntry kind="3" linkType="1" path="D:/eclipse/m2repo/com/adobe/AdobeSpellingUI/1.0/AdobeSpellingUI-1.0.swc" useDefaultLinkType="false"/>
      <libraryPathEntry kind="3" linkType="1" path="D:/eclipse/m2repo/com/adobe/AdobeSpellingEngine/1.0/AdobeSpellingEngine-1.0.swc" useDefaultLinkType="false"/>
      <libraryPathEntry kind="3" linkType="1" path="D:/eclipse/m2repo/com/adobe/flexlib/1.0/flexlib-1.0.swc" useDefaultLinkType="false"/>
    </libraryPath>
    <sourceAttachmentPath/>
  </compiler>
  <applications>
    <application path="colt-framework.as"/>
  </applications>
  <modules/>
  <buildCSSFiles/>
</actionScriptProperties>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cleaning a project in Flash Builder, basically, forces that project to recmopile.

I'll note that "cleaning" is not the same as exporting a release build.  Exprting a release build will remove a lot of "Debugging stuff" From your SWF and will give it a smaller size.

The Flex Compiler will automatically remove unused files/classes from your finished SWF.  Perhaps in your Maven build you are explicitly including files that are not used.

My best guess as to why your Flash Builder SWFs are smaller than the your Maven generated SWFs is because of different compiler settings.  You'd have to include compiler settings details for us to know for sure, though.

Comment: Compiler setting for swc project is added.

Answer (score 0):

There is no magic. Cleaning only means deleting all files which were created by previous build. You have probable checked "build after clean", which starts build again...

But, building by maven and compiling flex in eclipse are two different (independent) things. It looks there are different compiler configuration for eclipse and maven.